# Organizing multiple requests to a server

Tags: algorithm, request, server

I have some trouble even defining the problem. But the setup is this:

There are multiple devices that have to push data to a central server. We are talking about 2-3k devices. The question is how to organize the request and the retries in case of failure, so that we use the servers bandwidth most efficiently and we don't DDoS ourselves. Devices can't talk to each other directly.

Even search terms will be helpful, names of algorithms, scientific papers etc.

Comment: Off-topic: That is no programming question, but for network administration.

Comment: @Olaf I would hope that a network administrator should know the answer, but the necessary retry logic here is usually written by programmers.

Comment: @btilly: Maybe, but this question does not even mention a specific software, even less a specific programming question. Close as opinion based would also work. Pick one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The phrase you want is "exponential backoff".  It is a best practice in a wide variety of settings.  Here are the top 4 results of a Google search for that phrase:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_backoff
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/backoff
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.transientfaulthandling.exponentialbackoff.aspx